# Notepad++ Find in Files Filters

Tags: notepad++, file-types, find-in-files, file-filter

When using Notepad++ Find in Files feature is there a way to adjust the filter, so that it will search more than one filetype (e.g. *.c and *.h)?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Separate multiple filters with a semi-colon (;).

```
*.txt ; *.log
```

Or you can just use a space

```
*.txt *.log
```

Comment: Is there any way to negate a wildcard? ex: *.vb but not *.Designer.vb?

Comment: This is the standard open file dialog. I don't believe there is any negation. The best you can do is to carefully craft a filter that doesn't match the file you don't want. Maybe all files that have a letter or letter combination that prevents your file from showing, `*a*.vb`? or a file name length that doesn't match the length of the file you don't want, `?????.vb`?

Comment: @QuickDanger yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59419084/428724