# Notepad++ excluding find filters

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace, file-search, file-filter, find-in-files

In Notepad++ I want to search in all file types except one.

For instance: I want to search in all files but not `.class` files.

Can the Notepad++ filter can be configured to work this way?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Duplicate on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198829/notepad-find-in-files-filter-exclude

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't look like it can be *easily* configured to work this way.  Here are a couple of options for you

1. Use the filters dialog box to include all file extensions **except** the one you don't want (could get a bit long): [Notepad++ Find in Files Filters](https://superuser.com/questions/84601/notepad-find-in-files-filters)
2. Figure out how to use some code to write a plugin that will do it for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188070/notepad-file-filters

Comment: [Here's a script to generate a list of file extensions.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28706083/819417)

Comment: Note this answer is out of date. It now supports excludes. See other answer below

Answer (score 11):

Note, as of December 5th, 2019, Notepad++ 7.8.2 now supports exclude filters. The help documentation describes exclude filters in the [Find in Files tab](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#find-in-files-tab) section.

For example to exclude exe, zip and jar files, your 'find in files' filter will look like this;

`*.* !*.exe !*.zip !*.jar`

Relevant code change [here](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/commit/dc48cee5f7f4efe1f70e7269fe5e46ac8b861b1b).

Comment: This is a good news!

Answer (score 2):

her is a tip that can help :
you hide the folder that you want to exclude and then uncheck the **In hidden folders** in notepad so that it doesn't search in hidden folders:
[image]