# Advanced usage of Notepad++ find-in-files filter

Tags: notepad++

In the Notepad++ Find in Files dialog, there is a box for filter.  Normally you would enter something like `*.txt` in there.  Are there more advanced ways to use the filter?

Specifically, I am looking for the following functionality:

- Search all files **except** those of a specific extension
- Search multiple file extensions

Is this possible?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198829/notepad-find-in-file-filter-exclude

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While I don't know how to search in all files except of a type, you **can** search in multiple file types by separating them with semicolons.

As in:

```
*.txt;*.lua;*.toc
```

Comment: Awesome!  I was trying commas and what not.  This will help greatly, thank you.

Comment: Space can be used instead of semicolon as well. http://superuser.com/a/84609/508000